# How to fix {"message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL." } for my post method?

Tags: python, api, post, sqlite

This is the first time I'm creating an API for android retrofit. I modified this code according to the snippet I got online. The main functionality of the post method is to take the given parameters and store it in the sqlite3 database.

My schema of the following two tables:

```
sqlite> .schema spending
CREATE TABLE spending(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   date           TEXT      ,
   reason         TEXT      ,
   amount         INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE receiving(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   date           TEXT      ,
   from_reason           TEXT      ,
   amount         INTEGER
);
```

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask import jsonify

db_connect = create_engine('sqlite:///api.db')
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class AddSpending(Resource):
    def add_spending(self):
        try:
            _json = request.json
            _date = _json['date']
            _reason = _json['reason']
            _amount = _json['amount']
            # validate the received values
            if _date and _reason and _amount and request.method == 'POST':
                #do not save password as a plain text
                #_hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
                # save edits
                sql = "INSERT INTO spending(date, reason, amount) VALUES(%s, %s, %d)"
                data = (_date, _reason, _amount)
                #conn = mysql.connect()
                conn = db_connect.connect()
                cursor = db_connect.cursor()
                conn.cursor()
                conn.execute(sql, data)
                conn.commit()
                #resp = jsonify('Spending added successfully!')
                #resp.status_code = 200
                return
            else:
                return 404
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()        
            conn.close()

api.add_resource(AddSpending, '/spending_up',methods=['POST']) # Route_3
```

When a user passes data through this parameter. The data should be stored in the database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check your front-end probably you are sending **GET** request rather than a **POST**

Comment: I'm getting  HTTP/1.1" 405  when i run my code for .../spending_up

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you called you method as *add_spending* and shoud be named as *post*

change `def add_spending(self)` by `def post(self)`

the code for your api should look like that, without the **methods='POST'**

```
class AddSpending(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            _json = request.json
            _date = _json['date']
            _reason = _json['reason']
            _amount = _json['amount']
            # validate the received values
            if _date and _reason and _amount and request.method == 'POST':
                #do not save password as a plain text
                #_hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
                # save edits
                sql = "INSERT INTO spending(date, reason, amount) VALUES(%s, %s, %d)"
                data = (_date, _reason, _amount)
                #conn = mysql.connect()
                conn = db_connect.connect()
                cursor = db_connect.cursor()
                conn.cursor()
                conn.execute(sql, data)
                conn.commit()
                #resp = jsonify('Spending added successfully!')
                #resp.status_code = 200
                return
            else:
                return 404
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()        
            conn.close()

api.add_resource(AddSpending, '/spending_up') # Route_3
```

**UPDATE**

I just tried with a code similar to yours and worked

[image]

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

your repo code

[image]

Comment: Please look at the flask_restfull doc
https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html

Comment: I changed my method to post from add_spending but Now i'm getting this error    ` "GET /spending_up HTTP/1.1" 405 -` @Freddy

Comment: I modified my code as you mentioned to change my method from add_spending to post. But now I'm getting this error ** [09/Apr/2019 14:29:05] "GET /spending_up HTTP/1.1" 405 -**

Comment: you used GET, try with POST method, look at the example above. I updated the answer.

Comment: but I just tested it and it worked... haha.
Maybe you are confused about how to consume the api. 
For further details my telegram user is @fredd13r

Comment: check the new image added to the answer.